# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una búsqueda en dos sentencias select con UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, sql

En la tabla *entrada* se registran los artículos de los proveedores que no emiten factura. Y en la tabla *entrada_factura* se registran aquellos que sí tienen factura. Para mostrar todos los registros de ambas tablas tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT proveedor.nombre AS proveedor, null AS factura, 
articulo.nombre AS articulo, entrada.fecha_entrada, entrada.cantidad_entrada 
FROM proveedor INNER JOIN entrada ON proveedor.id_proveedor = entrada.proveedor 
INNER JOIN articulo ON entrada.articulo = articulo.id_articulo) a
 UNION ALL SELECT b.* FROM (SELECT proveedor.nombre AS proveedor,
 entrada_factura.factura, articulo.nombre AS articulo, entrada_factura.fecha_entrada, 
entrada_factura.cantidad_entrada FROM proveedor INNER JOIN 
entrada_factura ON proveedor.id_proveedor = entrada_factura.proveedor INNER JOIN
 articulo ON entrada_factura.articulo = articulo.id_articulo) 
b ORDER BY fecha_entrada ASC, articulo ASC;
```

Me gustaría poder filtrar los registros por factura, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Intenté con `WHERE factura LIKE '123%'` antes del `ORDER BY` pero me aparecen también los registros que tienen factura `NULL`.

BD:

1. articulo (`id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL, `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL);
2. proveedor (`id_proveedor` int(11) NOT NULL, `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL);
3. entrada (`id_entrada` int(11) NOT NULL, `proveedor` int(11) NOT NULL, `articulo` int(11) NOT NULL, `fecha_entrada` date NOT NULL, `cantidad_entrada` int(11) NOT NULL);
4. entrada_factura (`id_entrada_factura` int(11) NOT NULL, `factura` int(11) NOT NULL, `proveedor` int(11) NOT NULL, `articulo` int(11) NOT NULL, `fecha_entrada` date NOT NULL, `cantidad_entrada` int(11) NOT NULL);

Los datos que estoy utilizando:

```
INSERT INTO `articulo` (`id_articulo`, `nombre`) VALUES
(2, 'Acondicionador'), (1, 'Champu'), (4, 'Colonia'),
(3, 'Crema Corporal'), (6, 'Detergente'), (5, 'Lavaplatos');
INSERT INTO `proveedor` (`id_proveedor`, `nombre`) VALUES
(2, 'Beauty Rose'), (3, 'BioNaturals'), (1, 'Clean Mark');
INSERT INTO `entrada` (`id_entrada`, `proveedor`, `articulo`, `fecha_entrada`, `cantidad_entrada`) VALUES
(1, 1, 6, '2022-04-01', 20), (2, 1, 5, '2022-04-01', 20);
INSERT INTO `entrada_factura` (`id_entrada_factura`, `factura`, `proveedor`, `articulo`, `fecha_entrada`, `cantidad_entrada`) VALUES
(1, 123, 2, 1, '2022-04-04', 40), (2, 123, 2, 2, '2022-04-04', 40),
(3, 987, 3, 4, '2022-04-08', 45);
```

PD: Muchas gracias, las dos respuestas me dan el resultado que necesito

Comment: puedes modificar la pregunta añadiendo una tabla con el resultado esperado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los `NULL` que te aparecen son del primer `SELECT` por que el `WHERE` que propones únicamente afecta al segundo. Tienes dos opciones para resolverlo:

a) Encapsular tu `UNION ALL` en una subconsulta `c1` y entonces sí aplicar el `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM (
      SELECT proveedor.nombre AS proveedor,
        NULL AS factura,
        articulo.nombre AS articulo,
        entrada.fecha_entrada,
        entrada.cantidad_entrada
        FROM proveedor
        INNER JOIN entrada
          ON proveedor.id_proveedor = entrada.proveedor
        INNER JOIN articulo
          ON entrada.articulo = articulo.id_articulo) a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.*
    FROM (
      SELECT proveedor.nombre AS proveedor,
        entrada_factura.factura,
        articulo.nombre AS articulo,
        entrada_factura.fecha_entrada,
        entrada_factura.cantidad_entrada
        FROM proveedor
        INNER JOIN entrada_factura
          ON proveedor.id_proveedor = entrada_factura.proveedor
        INNER JOIN articulo
          ON entrada_factura.articulo = articulo.id_articulo) b  
  ) c1 WHERE factura LIKE '123%'
  ORDER BY fecha_entrada ASC, articulo ASC;
```

b) Ponerle el `WHERE` a los dos `SELECT` que une el `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
  SELECT proveedor.nombre AS proveedor,
    NULL AS factura,
    articulo.nombre AS articulo,
    entrada.fecha_entrada,
    entrada.cantidad_entrada
    FROM proveedor
    INNER JOIN entrada
      ON proveedor.id_proveedor = entrada.proveedor
    INNER JOIN articulo
      ON entrada.articulo = articulo.id_articulo) a
    WHERE factura LIKE '123%'
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*
FROM (
  SELECT proveedor.nombre AS proveedor,
    entrada_factura.factura,
    articulo.nombre AS articulo,
    entrada_factura.fecha_entrada,
    entrada_factura.cantidad_entrada
    FROM proveedor
    INNER JOIN entrada_factura
      ON proveedor.id_proveedor = entrada_factura.proveedor
    INNER JOIN articulo
      ON entrada_factura.articulo = articulo.id_articulo) b
  WHERE factura LIKE '123%'
  ORDER BY fecha_entrada ASC, articulo ASC;
```

Prefiero la primera para tener que definir la condición de seleccicón en un único sitio. Con la segunda, seguro que en algún momento te olvidas de conciliar ambos.

```
+-------------+---------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
| proveedor   | factura | articulo       | fecha_entrada | cantidad_entrada |
+-------------+---------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
| Beauty Rose |     123 | Acondicionador | 2022-04-04    |               40 |
| Beauty Rose |     123 | Champu         | 2022-04-04    |               40 |
+-------------+---------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
```

Aporto el dataset en SQL para realizar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE articulo(
  id_articulo int(11) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE proveedor(
  id_proveedor int(11) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE entrada(
  id_entrada int(11) NOT NULL,
  proveedor int(11) NOT NULL,
  articulo int(11) NOT NULL,
  fecha_entrada date NOT NULL,
  cantidad_entrada int(11) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE entrada_factura(
  id_entrada_factura int(11) NOT NULL,
  factura int(11) NOT NULL,
  proveedor int(11) NOT NULL,
  articulo int(11) NOT NULL,
  fecha_entrada date NOT NULL,
  cantidad_entrada int(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO articulo (id_articulo, nombre)
  VALUES (2, 'Acondicionador'), (1, 'Champu'), (4, 'Colonia'),
  (3, 'Crema Corporal'), (6, 'Detergente'), (5, 'Lavaplatos');
INSERT INTO proveedor (id_proveedor, nombre) VALUES 
  (2, 'Beauty Rose'), (3, 'BioNaturals'), (1, 'Clean Mark');
INSERT INTO entrada (id_entrada, proveedor, articulo, 
  fecha_entrada, cantidad_entrada) VALUES
  (1, 1, 6, '2022-04-01', 20), (2, 1, 5, '2022-04-01', 20); 
INSERT INTO entrada_factura (id_entrada_factura, factura, 
  proveedor, articulo, fecha_entrada, cantidad_entrada) VALUES
  (1, 123, 2, 1, '2022-04-04', 40), (2, 123, 2, 2, '2022-04-04', 40),
  (3, 987, 3, 4, '2022-04-08', 45);
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/209)

Comment: como ves mi solución?

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no sé muy bien qué pretende el OP uniendo los dos `SELECT` y desconozco si, aunque obtengas el mismo resultado, estés haciendo lo mismo que él. Igual con datos diferentes no llegas a lo mismo. Y, por optimizarla un poco, utiliza `JOIN` y `ON` en vez de `,` y `WHERE`, verás que se ejecuta más rápido.

Comment: vale muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución se basa en la unión de tablas, es totalmente distinto a como lo tienes pero funciona :

```
SELECT DISTINCT proveedor.nombre, factura,articulo.nombre,entrada.fecha_entrada, 
entrada.cantidad_entrada FROM proveedor,entrada_factura,articulo,entrada WHERE 
entrada_factura.id_entrada_factura=id_articulo AND 
id_proveedor=entrada_factura.proveedor AND 
factura LIKE '123%';
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/211)

Se trata sobre la unión de tablas mediante las claves primaria, Hago un **distinct** para que no haya valores repetidos, luego filtro por los nombres, selecciono las tablas implicadas compruebo que la `entrada_factura.id_entrada_factura=id_articulo` coincida y `entrada_factura.id_entrada_factura=id_articulo` para luego filtrar con el LIKE.

Otro modo de hacerlo seria con **RLIKE** una versión mejorada de **LIKE** seria de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT DISTINCT proveedor.nombre,factura,articulo.nombre,entrada.fecha_entrada,
entrada.cantidad_entrada FROM proveedor,entrada_factura,articulo,entrada WHERE
entrada_factura.id_entrada_factura=id_articulo AND
id_proveedor=entrada_factura.proveedor AND
factura RLIKE '123*';
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/212)

En lugar de usar **%** usa en su lugar * que esta mas orientado a programación y se entiende mejor pero no es lo único que cambia el **RLIKE** es la versión extendedida del **LIKE** el cual permite ***expresiones regulares***, por lo que esta herramienta es ***muy potente***.

El resultado de ambos es :

| nombre (proveedor) | factura | nombre (articulo) | fecha_entrada | cantidad_entrada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Beauty Rose | 123 | Acondicionador | 2022-04-01 | 20 |
| Beauty Rose | 123 | Champu | 2022-04-01 | 20 |

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo unir `UNION` con combinar `JOIN` o el producto cartesiano que estás usando y, como estás prescindiendo del primer `SELECT` del OP, por eso te sale el mismo resultado. Échale un vistazo y me confirmas...

Comment: Pues la elimine para echarle un ojo y creo que esta bien aunque no estoy seguro @DavidJP a lo mejor se puede explicar mejor ya que yo no me explico bien del todo por eso me metí aquí para mejorar mi expresión y aprender bien myslq